# In FFVII, when the final boss is defeated, can I return to the world map?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

Basically, when I defeat the last boss in FFVII, can I keep on playing the game? I.e. return to the world map and fight other super bosses? Or should I get everything done before the final fight?

I seem to remember completing it once and I just got credits and the game ended. Seems a bit lame not be able to play on!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Once you defeat the final boss, the ending FMVs and credits start to roll and eventually brings you to a screen with a never-ending pattern of stars. There's no way to get back to your playthrough - or even the main menu - without resetting the console.

So in short, yes, you remember correctly - get all the side quests completed before taking the last boss on.

Comment: There is no post game/clear game in _FFVII_.

Comment: However there is a save point right near the final boss. I seem to recall (maybe incorrect - can anyone back me up?) that you could climb down almost to the boss, save then walk away and carry on with everything externally.

Comment: Correct - from the final save point at the bottom of the Northern Cave, you can retrace your steps back up to the Highwind and the world map.